# How can I change the VSTS instance used when running Load Tests from Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, load-testing

Visual Studio 2015 makes it pretty easy to run a Visual Studio Load Test from Test Agents deployed in Azure.

However, when setting up the initial Load Test, I am asked which VSTS (i.e. xxxx.visualstudio.com) instance I want to connect to. After this is initially set I am never asked again when creating subsequent Load Tests.

I ran out of Load Test minutes on one VSTS instance and wanted to swap to another, where I had some additional minutes I could use.

How can I do this?

I found the only way I could was to copy and paste the entire Visual Studio solution and open it again, at which point I am presented with the 'Choose VSTS Instance for Load Test' dialog again.

Where is this setting stored?

**EDIT:** I realised that Visual Studio will ask you which VSTS instance to connect to after you restart it and begin a Load Test. However, it would still be good to know if there is a way of managing this via an in-program option, rather than having to kill it and restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution that is very simple.
Every time you restart Visual Studio 2015 and then begin a Load Test, you are presented with the dialog to choose VSTS instance.